# How to program moving a robot(e-puck) to the specific position?

Tags: position, webots

I'm newbie in programming world especially in webots.
Do you guys have any ideas/tutorial to move e-puck robot to a specific position in webots?
In my case, I'm trying to move the e-puck robot to the start position and when the robot finish performing wall following behavior, it will stop at the same position as start.
I'm searching for the ideas/tutorial to solve the problem, but in the end, I'm stuck. Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to take a look at the e-puck curriculum for Webots, particularly at the advanced part:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cyberbotics%27_Robot_Curriculum/Advanced_Programming_Exercises

The idea is the following: if you would like to do this in real conditions, implementing the odometry of the robot is a first step. A "goto" function based on the odometry would be the second step. The link contains information about this.
Ultimately, taking care of the other sensors (distance sensors, etc.) is the best solution, but it requires to do "SLAM". In this case, you can link your controller with a SLAM library (e.g. gmapping or Karto):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_localization_and_mapping

If you don't care about realism, you can get the absolute coordinates of the robot (using a Supervisor, or a GPS+Compass device). Writing a "goto" function on this is trivial.